# Show $A = \{f \in C([0,1]): f(x) > 0 \forall x \in [0,1] \}$ is open w.r.t sup norm: $\|f\|_{\infty, [0,1]} = sup_{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ Pf Verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

Show $A = \{f \in C([0,1]): f(x) > 0 \forall x \in [0,1] \}$ is open w.r.t sup norm: $\|f\|_{\infty, [0,1]} = sup_{x \in[0,1]}|f(x)|$

I wanted to know if I showed it properly.

**Attempt:**

So what we want to show is that $\forall \ g(x) \in A$ there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t $B_{\delta}(g) = \{h: \|g-h\|_{\infty} < \delta \} \subset A$.

By the Extreme Value Theorem all $f \in A$ attain a max and min, also we are given $f(x) > 0$ this means there exists $\delta > 0$ s.t $g(x) > \delta > 0 \  \forall x \in [0,1]$. Equivalently: $g(x) - \delta > 0$

So in order to satisfy $B_{\delta}(g) \subset A$, I need to show for all functions $h(x) \in B_{\delta}(g)$ that $h(x) > 0$.

*Here is where I'm not sure if I am doing the right thing.*

Consider $\|h-g\|_{\infty} < \delta$

$\Rightarrow sup_{x \in [0.1]}|h(x) - g(x)| < \delta$

$\Rightarrow -\delta < h(x) - g(x) < \delta \\ \Rightarrow h(x) > g(x) - \delta > 0$

This shows that $h(x) \in B_{\delta}(g) \subset A$

So the set $A$ is open.

**Remark:** This solution that I wrote doesn't "feel" complete to me> I used all of the conditions of the set, but I' feeling I missed something in my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's much more to say to this other than that your proof is correct.

Comment: I was going over it again and was thinking perhaps I should've used a fixed $x_{0}$ with the EVT by saying $f(x_{0})$ = min$f(x)$. Then $h(x) > g(x) - \delta > g(x_{0}) - \delta > 0$

Comment: This is the reasoning behind concluding that $g(x) - \delta > 0$ for all $x$, sure. One always has to judge what parts of a proof are elementary enough (relative to the difficulty of the result) to leave unsaid, otherwise almost all proofs would be ridiculously long and tedious to read. I'd say that that piece of reasoning is something I'd left unsaid in this proof but of course, this decision is ultimately somewhat subjective.